# I want to update my access database in my vb.net but always getting error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Here is my code

`Private Sub ButtonEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonEdit.Click
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        cb.QuotePrefix = "["
        cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"`

```
    ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").Rows(inc).Item("BARCODE") = TextBoxBarcode.Text
    ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").Rows(inc).Item("PRODUCT NAME") = TextBoxProductName.Text
    ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").Rows(inc).Item("PRINCIPAL") = TextBoxPrincipal.Text
    ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").Rows(inc).Item("BUYING PRICE") = TextBoxBuying.Text
    ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").Rows(inc).Item("SELLING PRICE") = TextBoxSelling.Text

    da.Update(ds, "ProductDatabase")
    MsgBox("Data successfully edited.")
```

Then showing this message:

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information

and the highlght part is

`da.Update(ds, "ProductDatabase")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that BARCODE is actually the primary key for the table you are editing, try putting [ and ] around the two word field names like "[PRODUCT NAME]".

Comment: Thank you @BCole . finally I succeed made BARCODE as my primary key  by adding these code : `Dim dColumn() As DataColumn = {ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").Columns("BARCODE")}
        ds.Tables("ProductDatabase").PrimaryKey = dColumn` but I got 1 problem again. When I run my program it was showing this messages: `Column 'BARCODE' is constrained to be unique.  Value '8993027133205' is already present` Do you know what is this?

Comment: Your table's primary key must be unique. And rather than define it in code, edit the table and make it the primary key. Your code will pick up on it automatically. If you can't have unique barcodes, then you will have to add a column that will contain unique values, like a autonumber, and make that the primary key. Whatever the key is, include that field in your select so the update works.

Comment: Wow It really works for me. The program was running. As you said, I made an auto number as my primary key. But, when I edit the data by clicking edit_button, my database didnt update at all. can you help me?